# Print dictionary values with list DB using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary of values like this:

```
indicator_keys = {
                  'i2': 'bla bla',
                  'i4': 'bla bla bla',
                  'i5': 'bla bla bla bla',
                  'i6': 'bla bla bla bla bla'
}
```

and I have a list like this :

```
a = ['i2','i4','i5','i6','i15']
b = ['i6','i3','i10','i6','i15']
```

I want to run a loop that will go through the dictionary and match if the item from my list matches one of the key to print the proper value but every loop I try even if there is only 1 match will prints the same sentence as the length of the WHOLE list (for example if only `i2` matched he will print the value 5 times because of the For loop) this is my code so far:

```
for index, key in enumerate(indicator_keys):
    for i in a:
        if str(i) in indicator_keys:
            print(indicator_keys[str(i)])
    for s in b:
        if str(s) in indicator_keys:
            print(indicator_keys[str(s)])
```

Comment: Why do you need the below outer loop?

```for index, key in enumerate(indicator_keys):```

Answer (score 1):

Try this will work

```
for d in indicator_keys:
   if d in a or d in b:
      print(d, indicator_keys[d])
```

Comment: thanks ! that worked perfect ! appreciate the help my friend :)

Comment: you're welcome, please mark it as helpful answer to help others

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner `for` loops when you're also using the `in` operator. Adding an additional `print` might help figure out what is happening. Your code is actually iterating `a` and `b` and printing the corresponding values from the `dict` for every element of `a` and `b`. And it does it as many times as the number of keys in the `dict`.

```py
In [1]: indicator_keys = {'i2': 'bla bla',
   ...:                   'i4': 'bla bla bla',
   ...:                   'i5': 'bla bla bla bla',
   ...:                   'i6': 'bla bla bla bla bla'}

In [2]: a = ['i2','i4','i5','i6','i15']
   ...: b = ['i6','i3','i10','i6','i15']

In [3]: for index, key in enumerate(indicator_keys):
   ...:     print("--- key: {} ---".format(key))
   ...:     for i in a:
   ...:         if i in indicator_keys:
   ...:             print(i, indicator_keys[i])
   ...:     for s in b:
   ...:         if s in indicator_keys:
   ...:             print(s, indicator_keys[s])
   ...:
--- key: i2 ---
i2 bla bla
i4 bla bla bla
i5 bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
--- key: i4 ---
i2 bla bla
i4 bla bla bla
i5 bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
--- key: i5 ---
i2 bla bla
i4 bla bla bla
i5 bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
--- key: i6 ---
i2 bla bla
i4 bla bla bla
i5 bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
```

Getting rid of the inner `for` loops should make it work as expected:

```py
In [4]: for key in indicator_keys:
   ...:     if key in a or key in b:
   ...:         print(key, indicator_keys[key])
   ...:
i2 bla bla
i4 bla bla bla
i5 bla bla bla bla
i6 bla bla bla bla bla
```

If you have a lot of elements in `a` and `b`, it might make sense to convert them to `set`.

Comment: Thank you mate ! appreciate that well guess more is not always better

Answer (score 1):

simplified with list comprehension:

```
keys = [item for item in indicator_keys if (item in a) or (item in b)]
print(keys)
```